# Getting android sdk dir with android gradle tools 1.10.+

Tags: android, gradle

Till now the follwing was working:

```
android.plugin.sdkDirectory
```

With Gradle 1.10+ however it is no longer possible. As a workaround I am currently using the following code:

```
def localProperties = new File(project.rootDir, "local.properties")
if (localProperties.exists()) {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
        properties.load(instr)
    }
    def sdkDirProp = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')

    if (sdkDirProp != null) {
        //YEAH WE HAVE THE ANDROID SDK DIR! NOW DO SOMETHING WITH IT!
    }
}
```

This however is a huge effort compared to the single line I was able to use before. Is there a solution I am missing?

Also the workaround might get deprecated since it uses a private constant FN_LOCAL_PROPERTIES = "local.properties" which I currently have hardcoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `android.sdkDirectory` instead of `android.plugin.sdkDirectory`

See https://plus.google.com/114432517923423045208/posts/NphSRvqAo6m

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed a simple solution.